# Convert the string from nested parentheses to indented outline format

Tags: c#, programming-challenge

> Convert the string:
>
> ```
> (id,created,employee(id,firstname,employeeType(id), lastname),location)
> ```
>
> to the following output:
>
> ```
> id
> created
> employee
> - id
> - firstname
> - employeeType
> -- id
> - lastname
> location
> ```

The solution I came up with is given below. I want to improve it, but without using regular expressions. Please help me to figure out the best way to approach this problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace FrontlineCodeChallenge_2017
{
    public class Program
    {   
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the input string");
            var providedString = Console.ReadLine();
            if (providedString == "")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the input string");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            var outerString = ParseTheGivenString(providedString);

            var finalArray = outerString.Split(',');

            foreach (var item in finalArray)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();   
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///Parse the input string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="workingString"></param>
        /// <returns>string</returns>
        public static string ParseTheGivenString(string workingString)
        {
            StringBuilder inputString = new StringBuilder(workingString);
            if (inputString[0] == '(')
            {
                int length = workingString.LastIndexOf(')');
                var formattedString = inputString.Remove(0, 1);
                var formattedStringOutput = formattedString.Remove(length - 1, 1);
                inputString = formattedStringOutput;
            }
            inputString = inputString.Replace(", ", ",");
            var inputreformattedString = inputString.Replace("(", ",(,");
            inputreformattedString = inputreformattedString.Replace(")", ",)");
            string[] workingArray = inputreformattedString.ToString().Split(',');
            List<string> collection = new List<string>();
            int openBracketCounter = 0;
            int closeBracketCounter = 0;
            var intermediateString = "";
            foreach (var item in workingArray)
            {
                if (item.IndexOf("(") != -1)
                {
                    openBracketCounter++;
                    intermediateString += item;
                    continue;
                }
                if (item.IndexOf(")") != -1)
                {
                    closeBracketCounter++;
                    intermediateString += item + ",";
                    if (openBracketCounter == closeBracketCounter && closeBracketCounter != 0)
                    {
                        intermediateString = intermediateString.Replace(",(", "(");
                        intermediateString = intermediateString.Replace(",)", ")");

                        collection.Add(intermediateString);

                        openBracketCounter = 0;
                        closeBracketCounter = 0;
                        intermediateString = "";
                    }
                    continue;
                }

                if (item.IndexOf("(") == -1 && item.IndexOf(")") == -1)
                {
                    if (openBracketCounter == 0)
                    {
                        collection.Add(item);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (openBracketCounter != closeBracketCounter)
                        {
                            intermediateString += item + ",";
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            if (openBracketCounter != closeBracketCounter)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Input String is not in a correct format, it is missing a bracket, Please check!");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            return CreateArrayOfProperties(collection);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create array of properties.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="stringsCollection"></param>
        /// <returns>string</returns>
        private static string CreateArrayOfProperties(List<string> stringsCollection)
        {
            int index = 0;
            List<string> properties = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in stringsCollection)
            {
                index = stringsCollection.IndexOf(item);
                if(index < stringsCollection.Count - 1 && stringsCollection[index + 1].Contains("("))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                if (item.Contains("("))
                {
                    index = stringsCollection.IndexOf(item);
                    properties.Add(stringsCollection[index - 1] + item);
                }
                else
                {
                    properties.Add(item);
                }
            }
            properties.Sort();
            List<string> finalString = new List<string>();
            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                int bracketIndex = property.IndexOf('(');
                int propertyIndex = properties.IndexOf(property);
                int innerIndex = 0, innerLength = 0, innerCount = 0;

                var workingProperty = property;

                int length = workingProperty.Length;
                int lastChar = workingProperty.LastIndexOf(',');
                if (lastChar == length - 1)
                {
                    workingProperty = workingProperty.Remove(lastChar, 1);
                }
                var subString = "";
                while (bracketIndex != -1)
                {
                    if (innerIndex > 1)
                    {
                    }
                    subString = findSubString(workingProperty, out innerIndex, out innerLength);
                    var finalSubString = RemoveAndInsert(workingProperty, subString, innerIndex, innerLength, ++innerCount);
                    bracketIndex = finalSubString.IndexOf('(');
                    workingProperty = finalSubString;
                }
                finalString.Add(workingProperty);
            }
            return string.Join(",", finalString.ToArray());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Finds substring in the provided string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="workingString"></param>
        /// <param name="index"></param>
        /// <param name="length"></param>
        /// <returns>string</returns>
        private static string findSubString(string workingString, out int index, out int length)
        {
            var start = workingString.IndexOf('(');
            var end = workingString.LastIndexOf(')');
            var subString = workingString.Substring(start + 1, end - start - 1);
            string[] array = subString.Split(',');
            Array.Sort(array, StringComparer.InvariantCulture);
            var sortedString = string.Join(",", array);
            index = start;
            length = end - start + 1;
            return sortedString;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Append Hyphens to the string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="str"></param>
        /// <param name="count"></param>
        /// <returns>string</returns>
        private static string appendHyphen(string str, int count)
        {
            var createString = "";
            StringBuilder createStr = new StringBuilder(createString);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                createStr.Append("-");
            }
            string[] strArray = str.Split(',');
            for (int i = 0; i < strArray.Length; i++)
            {
                strArray[i] = createStr.ToString() +" "+ strArray[i];
            }
            return string.Join(",", strArray);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Replace the old string with the new one.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="providedString"></param>
        /// <param name="subString"></param>
        /// <param name="index"></param>
        /// <param name="length"></param>
        /// <param name="count"></param>
        /// <returns>string</returns>
        private static string RemoveAndInsert(string providedString, string subString, int index, int length, int count)
        {            
            var bStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(providedString);
            bStringBuilder.Remove(index, length);            
            var insertString = appendHyphen(subString, count);
            insertString = ","+insertString;
            bStringBuilder.Insert(index, insertString);
            return bStringBuilder.ToString();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Why regular expression is not an option? I would use it for your task.

Comment: Is this for a technical interview? The namespace and the no regex comment makes me wonder...

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have gone a bit more complex than you need to. These tasks can usually be done by going through the string character by character. The only thing you need to keep track of is how nested you are in the string. Given that you want some behaviour with associated data, it's a good candidate for a class. Let's write one

```
public class Rewriter
{
    // Keeps track of how nested we are in the string
    private int level;
    private StringBuilder output;
    private bool isFirstNewLine;

    public string Rewrite(string input)
    {
        Reset(input.Length);
        foreach (var character in input)
        {
            switch (character)
            {
                case '(':
                    level++;
                    AppendNewLine();
                    break;
                case ')':
                    level--;
                    break;
                case ',':
                    AppendNewLine();
                    break;
                case ' ':
                    // trim property names by skipping spaces.
                    break;
                default:
                    output.Append(character);
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (level != 0)
        {
            // The brackets weren't balanced in the input string.
            throw new ArgumentException("Input is malformed");
        }
        return output.ToString();
    }

    private void Reset(int suggestedLength)
    {
        level = 0;
        output = new StringBuilder(suggestedLength);
        isFirstNewLine = true;
    }

    private void AppendNewLine()
    {
        if (isFirstNewLine)
        {
            isFirstNewLine = false;
            return;
        }
        output.AppendLine();
        if (level > 1)
        {
            output.Append('-', level - 1);
            output.Append(' ');
        }
    }
}
```

Then to use it, you just do

```
var rewriter = new Rewriter();
var output = rewriter.Rewrite(somestring);
```

---

Some comments on your code:

When checking for empty strings, this works but is less than ideal. It can sometimes be hard to see the difference between `" "` and `""` when you're scanning the code.

```
if (providedString == "")
```

Instead, use either `string.IsNullOrEmpty` or `string.IsNullOrWhitespace` to make your intention even clearer.

You use `var` in a lot of places but then use `int` even when the type is obvious. I'd prefer to see `var` everywhere.

All methods should be 'PascalCase' not 'camelCase' in C#.